# How to use for loop for a model

Tags: python, scipy

I understand that I have to put this all into a function and then call the function from a for loop ten times but I'm not sure how. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics as stats
plt.hist(list1, bins=100, alpha = 0.5)
array1 = np.array(list1)
array2 = np.array(list2)
array3 = np.array(list3)
# Run the t-test using scipy library
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(array1,array2)
```

Comment: use a loop with range(10

Answer (score 3):

Use range (for x in range(0,10)):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics as stats
import numpy as np
# Library for scientific statistics
import scipy.stats
for x in range(0,10):
  print(x)
  # Create two lists of random numbers that follow a normal ("Gaussian") distribution
  # Start with an empty list named "list1"
  list1 = []
  # Loop that runs 30 times - starts at 1, goes to 30
  for x in range(1,30):
    # Random numbers drawn from pool that has mean of 12 and standard deviation of 5
    value1 = random.gauss(12,5)
    # Add random value to the first list, list1
    list1.append(value1)
  print(list1)
  # Do the same with a second list
  list2 = []
  for x in range(1,30):
    # Random numbers drawn from pool that has mean of 14 and standard deviation of 4
    value2 = random.gauss(14,4)
    list2.append(value2)
  print(list2)
  # Create a histogram of the two lists using matplotlib library
  plt.hist(list1, bins=50, alpha = 0.5)
  plt.hist(list2, bins=50, alpha = 0.5)
  # Run a t-test on the two sets of data
  array1 = np.array(list1)
  array2 = np.array(list2)
  # Run the t-test using scipy library
  scipy.stats.ttest_ind(array1,array2)
```